# How to resolve the "Dependency Hell" in Delphi/Pascal projects? // source code modularized into several git submodules

Tags: delphi, pascal

Each project contains modularized source code and resides in its own respective Git repository, and they are linked through `git submodule`:

- project A depends on project B,
- project B depends on project C (version X),
- project A depends on project C (version Y),

with X and Y potentially being different.

Given these dependencies, a project A could have the following folder structure:

```
Project A\A.pas
Project A\Libs\Project B\B.pas
Project A\Libs\Project B\Libs\Project C\C.pas
Project A\Libs\Project C\C.pas
```

However, project A would have the following *non-working* `uses` clause:

```
uses
  B in 'Libs\Project B\B.pas',
  C in 'Libs\Project B\Libs\Project C\C.pas',
  C in 'Libs\Project C\C.pas';
```

It doesn't matter whether project A or project B added their dependency on project C second.

Is there a way to resolve this variant of the [Dependency Hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell)? If yes, how?

Comment: I don't think so. Unit names must be unique. You should solve the problem properly. You know what you need to do.

Comment: Project A *cant* depend on multiple versions of Project C.  If you link statically, only one `C.pas` unit can exist in A directly. And if you link dynamically, there can only be one BPL with C in it, so A and B have to share the same BPL.